# Excel 64bit C addin compilation issue

Tags: c, excel, 64-bit, add-in, mingw-w64

Here is a bit of C code that I'd like to turn into an Excel .XLL addin for Excel 2010 64bit.
The question is NOT if Excel 2010 can run 32bit addin, the code HAS to be 64bit, as I need to start a 64bit JVM from this addin.

When I compile it with Visual Studio 2012 it works.
When I compile this EXACT same code with mingw64, it compiles but Excel crashes (XLCALL32 is the 64 bit version from the Excel 2010 SDK).

**`c:\mingw\mingw64_rubenvb\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -m64 -shared -o test.xll test.c -L . -lXLCALL32`**

After long and frustrating efforts, I've found out that the problem is with the **Excel4** call.

If I replace that call with **Excel12** (from the XLCALL.CPP file that comes with the aforementioned SDK) and use XLOPER12 and XCHAR obviously, then it all works!

Does anybody have any insight into WHY this is?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "xlcall.h"

#define XL_MAX_STRING_LENGTH 255
#define JAVA_MAX_NUM_JVM_ARGS 20


char *xl_new_string(char *text)
{
    if (!text) return NULL;

    int len = strlen(text);
    if (len == 0) return NULL;
    if (len > XL_MAX_STRING_LENGTH) len = XL_MAX_STRING_LENGTH;

    char *p = (char *) malloc(len + 2);
    memcpy(p + 1, text, len + 1);
    p[0] = (char) len;
    return p;
}

void xl_show_message_box(char *text)
{
    XLOPER xStr, xInt;

    xStr.val.str = xl_new_string(text);
    xStr.xltype = xltypeStr;

    xInt.val.w = 3;
    xInt.xltype = xltypeInt;

    Excel4(xlcAlert, NULL, 2, &xStr, &xInt);
    free(xStr.val.str);
}



__declspec (dllexport) int __stdcall xlAutoOpen()
{
    char message[XL_MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    strcpy(message, "It's OPEN !");
    xl_show_message_box(message);

    return 0;
}


__declspec (dllexport) int __stdcall xlAutoClose()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think Excel4 is an obsolete API which doesn't work with x64 with non MSVC compiler. Most probably some compiler specific code is used wrongly in the old API.

Comment: Hi kan, thank you for your reply... Yes, this is the most obvious possible answer :) However how SURE are you this is indeed the case?

Comment: Difficult to say, RTFS only I believe... Any particular reason why do you need to use older API?